# How do i add multiple records to my database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

been working on a form. I want to add the information in the form to a database so i can show it in a calendar somewere else on the website.

I found some other code online but that only works for 1 value. and for some reason only 1 time. 
Now have this (working in wordpress btw)

```
function elh_insert_into_db() {

global $wpdb;
// creates my_table in database if not exists
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "table_form"; 
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
    `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` text NOT NULL,
    `email` text NOT NULL,
    `date` text NOT NULL,
    `starttijd` text NOT NULL,
    `eindtijd` text NOT NULL,
    `opmerkingen` text NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (`id`)
) $charset_collate;";
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
// starts output buffering
ob_start();
?>
<form action="#v_form" method="post" id="v_form">
    <label for="visitor_name"><h3>Naam:</h3></label>
        <input type="text" name="visitor_name" id="visitor_name" />

<label for="visitor_email"><h3>E-mail:</h3></label>
    <input type="email" name="visitor_email" id="visitor_email" />

<label for="visitor_date"><h3>Datum:</h3></label>
    <input type="date"  name="visitor_date" id="visitor_date" />

<label for="visitor_start_time"><h3>Starttijd:</h3></label>
    <input type="time"  name="visitor_start_time" id="visitor_start_time" />

<label for="visitor_end_time"><h3>Eindtijd:</h3></label>
    <input type="time"  name="visitor_end_time" id="visitor_end_time" />

    <label for="visitor_text"><h3>Opmerkingen:</h3></label>
        <input type="text" name="visitor_text" id="visitor_text" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Aanvragen" />
</form>
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
// does the inserting, in case the form is filled and submitted
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["visitor_name"] != "" ) {
$table = $wpdb->prefix."table_form";
$name = strip_tags($_POST["visitor_name"], "");
$wpdb->insert( 
    $table, 
    array( 
        'name' => $name
    )
);


    $html = "<p>check this is inserted in the database <strong>$name, $email, $date , $starttijd, 
$eindtijd, $opmerkingen</strong> what a succes!</p>";
}
// if the form is submitted but the name is empty
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["visitor_name"] == "" )
    $html .= "<p>You need to fill the required fields.</p>";
// outputs everything
return $html;

}
// adds a shortcode you can use: [insert-into-db]
add_shortcode('elh-db-insert', 'elh_insert_into_db');
```

Comment: So this is working, or it's not working?

Comment: It is not working right now

Comment: What isn't working? What is it supposed to do and what is it actually doing?

Comment: It is supposed to put the information from the form into a database called "table_form". At this point it only put the name into this database, and also only for the first input. If you fill out the form a second time it doenst do anything

Answer (score 0):

you only process / insert the name (form your code):

```
$name = strip_tags($_POST["visitor_name"], "");    
$wpdb->insert( 
    $table, 
    array( 
        'name' => $name
    )
)
```

Modify this section of code to add other information.  Each item from your $_POST needs to be processed.

Good starting point on forms (and so many other things!): https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
    function elh_insert_into_db() {
    global $wpdb;
    // creates nizam_table in database if not exists
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "nizam_table"; 
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
        `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` text NOT NULL,
        `email` text NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`id`)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
    // starts output buffering
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form action="#v_form" method="post" id="v_form">
        <label for="visitor_name"><h3>Hello there! What is your name?</h3></label>
        <input type="text" name="visitor_name" id="visitor_name" />
        <input type="text" name="visitor_email" id="visitor_email" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    // does the inserting, in case the form is filled and submitted
    if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["visitor_name"] && $_POST["visitor_email"]  != "" ) {
        $table = $wpdb->prefix."nizam_table";
        $name = strip_tags($_POST["visitor_name"], "");
        $email = strip_tags($_POST["visitor_email"], "");
        $wpdb->insert( 
            $table, 
            array( 
                'name' => $name,
                'email' => $email
            )
        );
        $html = "<p>Your name <strong>$name</strong> was successfully recorded. Thanks!!</p>";
    }
    // if the form is submitted but the name is empty
    if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["visitor_name"] == "" )
        $html .= "<p>You need to fill the required fields.</p>";
    // outputs everything
    return $html;     
}
// adds a shortcode you can use: [insert-into-db]
add_shortcode('elh-db-insert', 'elh_insert_into_db');
```